# ios - UIViewController does not display UIWebView does not display on iPad screen but does on iphone

Tags: ios, ios5

I just made and tested with the emulator a UIWebView that I attached to a controller which displayed a html page.

But when I did the same with the iPad emulator, it didn't render the html.

I did attach both the iPad and iPhone versions to the same controller. In the controller here is how I render the html:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"premium" ofType:@"html"];    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theWebView loadRequest:rq];
}
```

So on the iPad, did I have to drag from the storyboard to the .h file and register another IBOutlet UIWebView that is separate from the iPhone one?

The reason I am confused is that I have some pages of the app like this that I made before which work in iphone and ipad with only one registered IBOutlet UIWebView - but I forgot how I managed to get that to work :)

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any element you link to an IBOutlet in your iPhone Storyboard, you have to link it's iPad Storyboard counterpart to the same IBOutlet.

Comment: yes, but I am linking an entire UIWebView - and somehow I didn't have to do that twice for some of the other screens I have...just not sure how I did that :)